# « Ça m'a l'air sensé » : une manifestation du dativus ethicus?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

« Ça m'a l'air sensé. »

Comment analyser, du point de vue de la grammaire, le pronom **m'**?

- Est-ce le *dativus ethicus* dont on parle dans *Le bon usage, 14e éd.* (par Grevisse & Goosse, Duculot, 2008):

  > La langue familière emploie d'une manière expletive le pronom de la 1er ou de la 2e personne, pour exprimer l'intérét que le locuteur prend à l'action ou pour soliciter l'interlocuteur de s'intérésser à l'action (c'est le *dativus ethicus* de la grammaire latine).

  (§672(e), p. 865)

  Parmi les exemples qui suivent: « Allez-MOI mettre votre blouse » et « Regardez-MOI cette misère. »
- Ou est-ce, tout simplement, le pronom complément d'objet indirect qui correspondrait à: « ça a l'air sensé à moi. »

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ce n'est pas une tournure familière. C'est donc le deuxième choix qu'il faut retenir. La phrase indique que c'est de son propre avis qu'il s'agit (pour ma part, pour/en ce qui me concerne) :

> *Ça a l'air sensé **pour** moi.*

Comment: Et qu'est-ce que vous dites à propos le « nous » qui apparaît dans la citation suivante, pris [d'épisode no. 1 de LOU!](https://youtu.be/nQIjzXL_zeM?t=211):

Lou: Ne prononce plus jamais ce prénom! Mon cœur a été brisé par les sombres et implacables mâchoires d'un phacocchère aux nasaux putrides.
Mina: OK, tu nous fait carrément une crise de niveau 12.

Comment: Pas mieux : "Tu nous fais une crise" signifie "À nous, tu fais une crise..."

Comment: « à nous » veut dir quoi là?

Comment: Tu fais une crise devant nous, à notre attention.